# Time complexity of matrix chain multiplication

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a solved problem in "Introduction to Algorithms", by Cormen, et. al. 
Ch. 15, Section 15.2: Matrix Chain Multiplication. Pg. 373.

The objective is to parenthesize the matrix chain product **A1.A2.A3.....An** such that there are minimum number of scalar multiplications. 
For **Ai.Ai+1....Ak.Ak+1.....Aj**,
Matrix Ai has dimension pi-1xpi
The author comes up with the recursion

```
m[i,j] = 0 if i=j
       = min {m[i,k] + m[k+1] + pi-1.pk.pj}   where i goes from k to (j-1)   if i<j
```

(m[i,j] is the minimum number of scalar multiplications required for the product Ai....Aj)

So far I understood, but then the time complexity he says is O(n^3). 
When I look at the pseudo-code, there are 3 for loops, so its correct. But I don't understand this intuitively by looking at the recursion.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The final solution is to calculate `m[0,N]`. But all `m[i,j]` values need to be calculated before `m[0,N]` can be calculated. This makes it `O(N^2)`.

From the recursion formula you can see each `m[i,j]` calculation needs `O(N)` complexity.

So `O(N^3)` for the complete solution.

Comment: The final solution is m[1,N-1] not m[0,N]

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but useless. The thing to prove is theta(n)=n^3, and the loops take O(j-i+1), so it’s not obvious.

Answer (score 4):

There could be O(n^2) unique sub-problems to any MCM given problem and for every such sub-problem there could be O(n) splits possible.

So it is O(n^3).